# In SQL- How to partition database in two datasets namely test and control date sets based on customer based on attributes

Tags: sql

I need help - with partitioning the database by separating dataset into two separate multiple tables datasets: namely test and control sets in SQL where the rows are selected randomly. Please can someone help me what code i should use to partition the datasets into two data sets

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does it mean to select randomly AND based on some attributes?  In addition to being explicit about what you want, you need to tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and partitioning features are highly product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)